# How to deal with Date and Timezone in PHP with AWS API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK and Amazon's API is returning this timestamp below.

```
2013-04-23T13:18:00Z
```

The timestamp they are giving me seems to be in my timezone already.  Since it doesn't specify which timezone it is, I guess it's assumed to be my local time.  The wiki site for ISO 8601 also states...

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation, the time is assumed to be in local time.

But when I try to use it in PHP like [this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zph-ys4) it is converting it into my local timezone.  PHP's strtotime page says this...

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.

My question is why is strtotime converting it into my timezone if it's already in my timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Z" at the end of the date returned by Amazon means it's UTC. You will need to convert the timezone to have it be localized. You can do this by doing the following:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2013-04-23T13:18:00Z'); // Z = UTC
echo $date->format('H') . PHP_EOL;
//> 13
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); // -0700
echo $date->format('H') . PHP_EOL;
//> 06
```

**Update:** Read all the comments for the full solution.

Comment: According to the wiki for ISO 8601 that this time given from Amazon is already in my local time.`Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.` So when I try and convert it, it converts it to the wrong time since it was already at the right time.

Comment: Is Amazon providing the wrong format?  Or is PHP converting it when it really should not?

Comment: A timezone is provided correctly in the date that you included in your question. The timezone is UTC +0000. The Z means "zero" or +0000. This is valid in ISO 8601. Unless your timezone is UTC +0000 you will need to convert it.

Comment: Jeremy...I think the problem might be with Amazon's dates they are passing back.  I'm calling getMetricStatistics from the CloudWatch client with the start date of `2013-04-24T09:31:00-06:00` and end date of `2013-04-24T10:31:00-06:00` (Just the last hour of data). These are some of the dates it's giving back to me... 2013-04-24T10:26:00Z, 2013-04-24T10:01:00Z, 2013-04-24T10:21:00Z, 2013-04-24T10:06:00Z.  Its as if the API is passing back my local times but with the timezone of Z or zero or zulu or +00:00.  Do you see?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Mind sharing the code you are using with the SDK? I could look into easier knowing what the code looks like.

Comment: Hey, try this instead: https://gist.github.com/jeremeamia/5483957
Don't pre-format your dates. Just pass in the integer values and let the SDK handle formatting it.

Comment: That seems to be working now.  I swear I was doing that in the beginning and it wasn't working.  Oh well, it's working now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yay! I'm glad it's working now. Looking into the difficulty you were having, I found an issue in Guzzle. I made [this PR to Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/308) which will fix the issue downstream in later versions.